# How to get the value of an annotated variable?

Tags: variables, annotations

So, I'm writing a method that will get annotated variables (doubles) and store them in a map. The variables are elements of an object. The name of the variable should be the key and its value - the parameter.

```
    public void putInMap() {
      Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

      for (Field v: fields) {           
          if (v.isAnnotationPresent(Annotation.class))
              map.put(v.getName(), *value here* );
      }     
    }
```

My question is how to get the value of the variable (which is now a Field) so that I could put it in my map?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for (Field v : fields) {
    if (v.isAnnotationPresent(Annotation.class)) {
        v.setAccessible(true);
        map.put(v.getName(), v.get(this));  
    }
}
```